# Need to find a (x,y) coordinate based on an angle

Tags: javascript, trigonometry, angle

So I'm stumped. I didn't know trigonometry before this, and I've been learning but nothing seems to be working.

[image]

So a few things to note: In html, cartesian origin(0,0) is the top left corner of the screen. DIVS natural rotation is 0deg or ---->this way.

I need to find the x,y point noted by the ? mark in the problem.

```
$('#wrapper').on('click', function(e){
    mouseX = e.pageX;
    mouseY= e.pageY;

    var angle  = getAngle(mouseX,Rocket.centerX,mouseY,Rocket.centerY);
    var angleDistance = Math.sqrt((Math.pow((mouseX - (Rocket.left+Rocket.halfX)),2)) + (Math.pow((mouseY-(Rocket.top+Rocket.halfY)),2)));
    var cp2Angle = -90 +(angle*2);
    var invCP2Angle = 90+ angle;
    var cp2Distance = angleDistance*.5;
    //Red Line
    $(this).append('<div class="line" style="transform-origin:left center;width:'+(Math.round(angleDistance))+'px;top:'+(Rocket.top+Rocket.halfY)+'px;left:'+(Rocket.left+Rocket.halfX)+'px;transform:rotate('+(Math.round(angle))+'deg);"></div>');
     //Blue Line
     $(this).append('<div class="line" style="background:#0000FF;transform-origin:left center;width:'+Math.round(cp2Distance)+'px;top:'+(mouseY)+'px;left:'+(mouseX)+'px;transform:rotate('+(Math.round(cp2Angle))+'deg);"></div>');
}
function getAngle(x2,x1,y2,y1){
    var angle = Math.degrees(Math.atan2(y2-y1,x2-x1));
    return angle;
}
Math.degrees = function(radians) {
  return (radians * 180) / Math.PI;
};
```

So this might be confusing. Basically when I click on the page, i calculate the angle between my custom origin and the mouse points using Math.atan2(); I also calculate the distance using Math.sqrt((Math.pow((x2 - x1),2)) + (Math.pow((y2-y1),2)));

The blue line length is half the length of the red line, but the angle changes, based on the angle of the red line.

When the red line angle = 0deg(a flat line), the blue line angle will be -90(or straight up, at red line -45 deg, the blue line will be -180(or flat), and at Red Line -90, the blue line will be -270 deg(or straight down). The formula is -90 +(angle*2)

I need to know the other end point of the blue line. The lines only exist to debug, but the point is needed because I have an animation where I animate a rocket on a bezier curve, and I need to change the control point based on the angle of the mouse click, if there's abetter way to calculate that without trigonometry, then let me know.

I read that the angle is the same as the slope of the line and to find it by using Math.tan(angle in radians). Sometimes the triangle will be a right triangle for instance if the first angle is 0 deg, sometimes it won't be a triangle at all, but a straight line down, for instance if they click -90.

I've also tried polar coordinates thought I wasn't sure which angle to use:

```
var polarX = mouseX-(cp2Distance * Math.cos(Math.radians(invCP2Angle)));
var polarY = mouseY- (cp2Distance * Math.sin(Math.radians(invCP2Angle)));
```

Comment: I wonder if this is appropriate for mathematics.stackexchange ... ? Regardless, I'll try to help out if you can wait a little while... :D

Comment: Thanks for embedding image!

Comment: You didn't know trigonometry? Isn't that high school math?

Comment: @Barmar: By your comments I assume that you consider yourself to be an expert on trig?

Comment: Not an expert, but I still remember SOHCAHTOA :)

Comment: I actually hated math in highschool, I think I failed algebra. Ironic that I decided to be a developer.

I know SOHCAHTOA too, but this is an oblique triangle which wouldn't help. I'm not sure how to do the law of sines or law of cosines without knowing the length of the third missing side.

Comment: The convention of angle sign is the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know javascript well, so instead of giving you code, I'll just give you the formulae. On the figure below, I give you the conventions used.

[image]

```
x3 = x2 + cos(brownAngle + greenAngle) * d2
y3 = y2 + sin(brownAngle + greenAngle) * d2
```

If I understand you correctly, you have already `d2 = 0.5 * d1`, `d1`, `(x2, y2)` as well as the angles. This should then just be a matter of plugging these values into the above formulae.

Comment: Yes! I believe this works. This is the polar coord formula right? (angle, r)?

I tried this before but I think I mucked up the end values or wasn't adding them to 2 coord's.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let `A`, `B` and `C` be the three points.

```
AB = ( cos(angle1), sin(angle1) ) * length1
B = A + B
BC = ( cos(angle1+angle2), sin(angle1+angle2) ) * length2
C = B + BC
```

In your case,

```
A = ( 0, 0 )
angle1 = 31°
length1 = 655
angle2 = 152°
length2 = 328
```

Then,

```
C = ( Math.cos(31*Math.PI/180), Math.sin(31*Math.PI/180) ) * 655 +
    ( Math.cos(152*Math.PI/180), Math.sin(152*Math.PI/180) ) * 328
  = ( Math.cos(31*Math.PI/180) * 655 + Math.cos(183*Math.PI/180) * 328,
      Math.sin(31*Math.PI/180) * 655 + Math.sin(183*Math.PI/180) * 328 )
  = ( 233.8940945603834, 320.1837454184)
```